# JSON extraction based on condition in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract user id from the below json response. But I should only extract user id when the absent attribute is "false".

"availableUsers":[
{
"userId" : 6492,
"workDate" : "08 07 2020 00 00 00",
"workDay" : 6,
"workShortName" : "1430-2330_RCO",
"workTimes" : "14:30 - 23:30",
"Layer" : 4,
"earliestStartTime" : null,
"latestEndTime" : null,
"otaEntryAllowed" : false,
"isDayLocked" : false,
"isDayOff" : false,
"TimeType" : "Overtime",
"absent" : false,
"comment" : "",
},
{
"userId" : 6493,
"workDate" : "08 07 2020 00 00 00",
"workDay" : 6,
"workShortName" : "1430-2330_RCO",
"workTimes" : "14:30 - 23:30",
"Layer" : 4,
"earliestStartTime" : null,
"latestEndTime" : null,
"otaEntryAllowed" : false,
"isDayLocked" : false,
"isDayOff" : false,
"TimeType" : "Overtime",
"absent" : true,
"comment" : "",
}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) there are [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) therefore you can extract the `userId` attribute value for the "absent" users as:

```
$.availableUsers[?(@.absent == false)].userId
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)